# Android studio “view mode” bar, how to remove?

Tags: android, android-studio

There is this bar called "view mode" according to [Androids documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor), the one marked 6 on this picture:

[image: picture]

Now I really want to get rid of that bar, it wastes a ton of space, and has keymappings anyway. I literally cant find anywhere in the IDE or on the web on how to remove it. Please anyone help!

Comment: Are you talking about the attributes window ? or the bar with 3 image buttons ?

Comment: No I'm refering to the bar where u can choose which view you would like. code, split or design.

Comment: why you want to remove it?

Comment: @MohamedAbdelraZek I literally write it in the post.. "it wastes a ton of space, and has keymappings anyway"

Comment: you can switch to Code section

Comment: That doesnt remove the bar.